# Trying to automate the detection of an expired date in HTML (and send a trigger)

Tags: php, wordpress, automation

I have an events directory with hundreds of events.

I can stream the dates of each event onto a simple HTML page with the date that the event happened.

What I'd like is that there is a trigger to when an event has expired which can be determined by the HTML on the page. So for example:

```
<p>This ABC event is on May 25th 2020</p>
```

This date has obviously passed (question crated on May 27th 2020) so the bot (running once a day) would see that ABC event has passed (is outdated) and therefore trigger an action like sending an email.

Any idea of a platform or tool that could make this happen?

I am hosting on WordPress if that helps...

Comment: Why determined by the HTML on the page? Why not based on the data that put the HTML on your page? Write the PHP.

Comment: What prevents you specifically to detect the "obviously passed" events? Is it safe to trigger events each day even if events are from a previous than past the event passed date?

Comment: I want to take a specific action after the event has expired hence why I need it done once a day @hakre

Comment: And the day after it's fine to take the exact same action for the event that expired and was actioned already the day before? And what prevents you from doing so?